# ZF3 multiple database adapters

Tags: php, zend-framework, factory, zf3

in ZF2 it was possible to configurate multiple adapters like this in the `module.config.php`:

```php
'db' => array(
    'adapters'=>array(
        'db1' => array(
            'driver' => 'Pdo',
            'dsn' => 'mysql:dbname=zf2;host=localhost',
            'driver_options' => array(
                PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => 'SET NAMES \'UTF8\''
            ),
            'username' => 'zf2',
            'password' => 'zf2test',
        ),
        'db2' => array(
            'driver' => 'Pdo',
            'dsn' => 'mysql:dbname=zf1;host=localhost',
            'driver_options' => array(
                PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => 'SET NAMES \'UTF8\''
            ),
            'username' => 'zf1',
            'password' => 'zf1test',
        ),
    )

),
```

In the controller factory I could get them via the ServiceManager:

```php
class AlbumControllerFactory implements FactoryInterface
{

public function createService(ServiceLocatorInterface $serviceLocator)
    {
        $albumTable = $serviceLocator->getServiceLocator()->get('Album\Model\AlbumTable');
        $db1Adapter = $serviceLocator->getServiceLocator()->get('db1');
        $db2Adapter = $serviceLocator->getServiceLocator()->get('db2');

        return new AlbumController($albumTable, $db1Adapter, $db2Adapter);
    }
}
```

Now I'm trying to do the same in Zend Framework 3 - but this nested array configuration doesn't work:

```php
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Zend\Db\Adapter\Exception\InvalidArgumentException' with message 'createDriver expects a "driver" key to be present inside the parameters' in /var/www/USER/teckert/zf3/vendor/zendframework/zend-db/src/Adapter/Adapter.php:262
```

I think that in ZF 2 the `adapters` key are already handled when the dbAdapter is trying to create the driver - but this is not happening in ZF 3.

Any hints are warmly welcomed...

The manual of the [zend-db with the adapters section](https://zendframework.github.io/zend-db/adapter/) wasn't clear enough for me

**EDIT**

According to [this doc](https://zendframework.github.io/zend-servicemanager/configuring-the-service-manager/#abstract-factories) I've added the following snippet to the global config file:

```php
'service_manager' => [
    'abstract_factories' => [
        \Zend\Db\Adapter\AdapterAbstractServiceFactory::class,
    ],
],
```

While trying to get the dbAdapter with `$container->get('db1')` in my `AlbumTableFactory` I get this error:

```php
Unable to resolve service "db1 to a factory; are you certain you provided it during configuration?
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay I finally resolved the problem.

As mentioned by @Pieter I needed the following array content in my `config.php`:

```php
'service_manager' => [
    'abstract_factories' => [
        \Zend\Db\Adapter\AdapterAbstractServiceFactory::class,
    ],
],
```

Additionally I had to change the process my classes and dependent factories are talking to each other.

1. `AlbumControllerFactory` is called and get's the dependent `AlbumTable` service (`$container->get(AlbumTable::class);`) which then triggers the `AlbumTableFactory`
2. `AlbumTableFactory` then is preparing the constructor injection for the  `AlbumTable` with `$tableGateway = $container->get(AlbumTableGateway::class);`
3. Now I combined the logic from the `AlbumTableFactory` and the `AlbumTableGatewayFactory` into one `AbstractFactoryInterface` (I removed the AlbumTableGatewayFactory completely)

```php
// AlbumTableFactory implements AbstractFactoryInterface

public function __invoke(ContainerInterface $container, $requestedName, array $options = null)
{
    $dbAdapter = $container->get('db1');
    $resultSetPrototype = new ResultSet();
    $resultSetPrototype->setArrayObjectPrototype(new Album());

    $tableGateway = new TableGateway('album', $dbAdapter, null, $resultSetPrototype);

    return new AlbumTable($tableGateway);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you've added `Zend\Db\Adapter\AdapterAbstractServiceFactory` to the `abstract_factories` array of the ServiceManager configuration.
This abstract factory is responsible for instantiating the individual database adapters. Also, check whether your `Album\Model\AlbumTable` factory retrieves the database adapter with the correct name.

Comment: Don't forget that `Zend\Db` module must also be installed. It is not included by default in Zend Framework 3.